# Pandas Data Frame Filtering Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have the following data frame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1990,7,1000],[1990,8,2500],[1990,9,2500],[1990,9,1500],[1991,1,250],[1991,2,350],[1991,3,350],[1991,7,450]], columns = ['year','month','data1'])

year    month    data1
1990      7      1000
1990      8      2500
1990      9      2500
1990      9      1500
1991      1      250
1991      2      350
1991      3      350
1991      7      450
```

I would like to filter the data such that it won't contain data with month/year 07/1990, 08/1990 and 01/1991.
I can do for each combination month/year as follow:

```
df = df.loc[(df.year != 1990) | (df.month != 7)]
```

But it is not efficient if there are many combinations month/year. Is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do:

```
mask = ~df[['year', 'month']].apply(tuple, 1).isin([(1990, 7), (1990, 8), (1991, 1)])
print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   year  month  data1
2  1990      9   2500
3  1990      9   1500
5  1991      2    350
6  1991      3    350
7  1991      7    450
```

Answer (score 10):

Even faster (roughly 3x than the elegant version of @DaniMesejo applying `tuple`). But also it relies on the knowledge that months are bounded to (well below) 100, so less generalizable:

```
mask = ~(df.year*100 + df.month).isin({199007, 199008, 199101})
df[mask]

# out:
   year  month  data1
2  1990      9   2500
3  1990      9   1500
5  1991      2    350
6  1991      3    350
7  1991      7    450
```

How come this is 3x faster than the tuples solution? (Tricks for speed):

1. All vectorized operations and no `apply`.
2. No string operations, all ints.
3. Using `.isin()` with **a set** as argument (not a list).

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `merge`

```
out = df.drop(df.reset_index().merge(pd.DataFrame({'year':[1990,1990,1991],'month':[7,8,1]}))['index'])
   year  month  data1
2  1990      9   2500
3  1990      9   1500
5  1991      2    350
6  1991      3    350
7  1991      7    450
```

And small improvement

```
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'year':[1990,1990,1991],'month':[7,8,1]}),indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
   year  month  data1     _merge
2  1990      9   2500  left_only
3  1990      9   1500  left_only
5  1991      2    350  left_only
6  1991      3    350  left_only
7  1991      7    450  left_only
```

Based on my test this should be fast than apply tuple method ~

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]
just iterate over your df and get all indexes to delete:

```
dates_to_avoid = [(1990, 7), (1990, 8), (1991, 1)])
index_to_delete = [row.index for row in df.itertuples() if (row.year, row.month) in dates_to_avoid]
```

Then:

```
df = df.loc[~df.index.isin(index_to_delete)]
```

Here the keyword `~` will avoid all values from the list.

Comment: You filter out all years and months from lists. OP needs to filter only some combinations like 07/1990, 08/1990, and 01/1991. For example, 07/1991 should stay in the table and your code will remove it.

Comment: downvoted because this isn't an answer to this problem - it will filter out all rather than particular.

Comment: that is incorrect and doesn't give the result the OP wants. All pairs of `years_to_avoid` and `months_to_avoid` will be excluded, rather than specific ones.

Comment: yes, it was a bad interpretation, I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You can add a value for yyyymm and then use this to remove the data you want.

```
df['yyyymm'] = df['year'].astype(str) + df['month'].astype(str).zfill(2)
df = df.loc[(df.yyyymm != '199007') & (df.yyyymm != '199008') & (df.yyyymm != '199101')]
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'zfill'`

Comment: also, that's like attaching a grand piano to your legs before running the 100m dash... ;-)  And, last but not least: it modifies the columns of `df`.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html. it does :)

Comment: yes, `Series.str` does, not `Series.astype(str)`...

Answer (score 2):

Set the `year` and `month` as indices, filter on the indices with `isin` and a `callable` and reset the index:

```
(
    df.set_index(["year", "month"])
    .loc[lambda x: ~x.index.isin([(1990, 7), (1990, 8), (1991, 1)])]
    .reset_index()
)


year    month   data1
0   1990    9   2500
1   1990    9   1500
2   1991    2   350
3   1991    3   350
4   1991    7   450
```

Alternatively, you can use the `drop` function to drop the rows you are not interested in, and reset the index:

```
(df.set_index(["year", "month"], drop = False)
 .drop([(1990, 7), (1990, 8), (1991, 1)])
 .reset_index(drop = True)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function

```
def filter(row):
  # Add other conditions and just return row accordingly
  if ((row.year != 1990) | (row.month != 7)):
    return True
  return False

mask = df.apply(filter,axis=1)
df[mask]
```